# What is the best way to run a Python function after some PyQt5 QThread classes finish work?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qthread

I'm using PyQt5 and Python3, I use 3 QThread classes to run something and after they are done I need to execute a 4th QThread class. But the execution of the 4th need to take place after all of the QThread classes finish work, or only 2 or only 1. It must not run while the first 3 are working.
  I looked on the internet but I couldn't find a solution. My code looks like this:

```
 class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            file_path = os.path.abspath('builder_gui.ui')
            uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
            self.obj1 = TasksThread1(self.comboBox.currentText(),self.comboBox_6.currentText())
            self.obj2 = TasksThread2(self.comboBox_2.currentText(),self.comboBox_5.currentText())
            self.obj3 = TasksThread3(self.comboBox_3.currentText(),self.comboBox_4.currentText())
            self.obj4 = TasksThread4()
            self.menubar.setNativeMenuBar(False)
            self.progressVal = 1
            self.cwd = os.getcwd()
            self.obj1.newValueProgress.connect(self.increment_progress)
            self.obj1.message.connect(self.status_bar)
            self.obj2.newValueProgress.connect(self.increment_progress)
            self.obj2.message.connect(self.status_bar)
            self.obj3.newValueProgress.connect(self.increment_progress)
            self.obj3.message.connect(self.status_bar)
            self.obj4.newValueProgress.connect(self.increment_progress)
            self.obj4.message.connect(self.status_bar)
            self.obj4.doneSignal.connect(self.calculate_done_limit)
            self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.execute_build_script)
    def calculate_done_limit(self):
        limitCalc = 100 - int(self.progressBar.value())
        self.increment_progress(limitCalc)

    def run_gits_all(self):
        if self.crowdTwistCheck.isChecked():
            self.obj1.start()
        else:
            pass
        if self.ThemeCheck.isChecked():
            self.obj2.start()
        else:
            pass
        if self.mainAwsCheck.isChecked():
            self.obj3.start()
        else:
            pass

    def execute_build_script(self):
        self.progressBar.setValue(1)
        self.progressVal = 1
        self.run_gits_all()

    def execute_last_part(self):
        self.obj4.start()

    def status_bar(self, value_in):
        read1 = self.textBrowser.toPlainText()
        self.textBrowser.setText(read1 + "\n" + value_in)

    def increment_progress(self,valueIn):
        self.progressVal += valueIn
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.progressVal)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My first 3 QThreads are like this:

```
class TasksThread1(QThread):
    newValueProgress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    message = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    doneSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, branch, git):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.branch = branch
        self.git = git

    def remove_folder(self):
        do_something_1

    def CrowdTwistRepo(self):
        do_something_2

    def run(self):
        self.remove_folder()
        self.CrowdTwistRepo()
```

My last QThread looks like this:

```
class TasksThread4(QThread):
    newValueProgress = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    message = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    doneSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def gulp_sass_function(self):
        do_something_1

    def gulp_uglify_function(self):
        do_something_2

    def zipping_function(self):
        do_something_3

    def run(self):
        self.gulp_sass_function()
        self.gulp_uglify_function()
        self.zipping_function()
```

If I run the code, all of the QThreads start and I want my 4th QThread to start only after the first 3 have done working. I used QThreads to improve the GUI experience, the GUI froze alot.

thanks,

Comment: Use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#module-queue). When it's empty, start the other thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your first 3 threads are done, send a signal. Then connect this signal to a function that will start the last thread.

Comment: I made 3 signals, each QThread has one doneSignal. But the first one to finish will run the 4th QThread, I don't want this.

Comment: Just create 3 flags. Only start the 4th one when the 3 flags are set. Flags are good, but in your case a `QSemaphore` might be more appropriate

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I never used QSemaphore, I'm new in Qt.I'll try it tomorrow and bring back an answer.

Comment: To be honest I'd suggest just decrementing an integer each time the slot is called. Then only launch the 4th thread if the integer has been decremented 3 times.